# How can I merge state and props to control visibility of alert in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have an alert component that is invisible by default, and when something happens (e.g. click) in the parent component the alert component will be visible. Inside the alert component, there is a close button to make the component invisible again. I am new to react and I found it quite difficult to implement.

Here is my current solution:

The alert component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Alert = ({show, style, message}) => {

    const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(show);

    useEffect(() => {
        setVisibility(show);
    },[show]);

    return (
        <>
        {(visibility)?(
            <div className="col">
              <div className={"alert shadow alert-"+style} role="alert">
                {message}
                <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={(e) => {
                  setVisibility(false);
                }}>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
        ):(<></>)}
        </>
    );


}

export default Alert;
```

The parent component has a state to manage it.

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    'show': false,
    'style':'',
    'message':''
  });
```

```
<Alert show={alert.show} style={alert.style} message={alert.message} />
<button onClick={(e) => {

  setAlert({
    'show':false, 
    'style':'',
    'message':''
  });
  setAlert({
    'show':true, 
    'style':'success',
    'message':'Thank you!'
  });
}>
  show
</button>
```

The problem is that because the prop `show` is not changed when clicking on the close button inside the alert component when I click on the button in the parent component, the prop `show` is still `true` so it won't render the alert component. The workaround I am using is to set the alert prop `show` to false before setting it to `true` again. This is not very neat. Is there a better way to combine the prop and the state to decide the visibility of the alert?

Comment: Hi Li, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a function to hide the `Alert` in the parent component itself and pass it down to the child component.

```
const hideAlert = () => {
   setAlert(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     show: !prevState.show
   }))
}
```

Then you can pass this to `Alert` component,

```
<Alert show={alert.show} style={alert.style} message={alert.message} hideAlert={hideAlert}/>
```

In the alert component, no need to store props into the state again. You should directly use props,

```
const Alert = ({show, style, message, hideAlert}) => {
  return (
    <>
      { show ? <div className="col">  //directly use props here to show alert
          <div className={"alert shadow alert-"+style} role="alert">
            {message}
            <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={hideAlert}>
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        : 
        <></>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5ecza8)

Comment: Thanks, this works better. Is there a way to include the hide function in the alert component so when it's used by multiple parent components there is no need to rewrite it many times?

Comment: If you want hide function in alert component, then your parent component will not aware of state change. To change state in parent component you again need a separate function to tell parent component that state has been changed. So i advise to not move hide function in Alert component, keep it in parent component only.